# MediaStreamSource and CryptoStream

Tags: c#, silverlight

**Scenario**: We have a silverlight 5 OOB application that is going to be published offline(DVD ROM). This application serves as a media player for some educational contents. In order to protect the video files that are shipped with DVD ROM, I decided to encrypt the video files with a key unique to each user, ship the content and decrypt it when needed to play.

**Problem**: How is it possble to decrypt the media on the fly progressively? I don't want to decrypt the whole file at once for memory and performance issues. `MediaElement` supports source of type stream, but when I decrypt the video file using `CryptoStream` and pass it to the `MediaElement.SetSource` method, the following exception is thrown:

```
{System.Windows.Media.DrmException: 3121 3121 An error has occurred.
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MethodEx(IntPtr ptr, String name, CValue[] cvData)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MediaElement_SetStreamSource(MediaElement element, Stream stream)
   at System.Windows.Controls.MediaElement.SetSource(Stream stream)
   at SilverlightApplication4.MainPage.button1_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Control.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(Control ctrl, EventArgs e)
   at MS.Internal.JoltHelper.FireEvent(IntPtr unmanagedObj, IntPtr unmanagedObjArgs, Int32 argsTypeIndex, Int32 actualArgsTypeIndex, String eventName, UInt32 flags)}
```

I use AES alorithm is `AesManaged` class for cryptographics operations.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where are you planning on storing the AES key? If it's on the disk along with the video, you're not really protecting yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set MediaElement.SetSource as the crypto stream or as a stream wrapping it ?

```
FileStream stream = new FileStream(“mymedia.avi”, FileMode.Open,FileAccess.Read);
CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(stream, alg.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read);
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(cs);
```

As someone already pointed out, don't store the key along with the product. It's really easy to find the key stored in a binary.